# Convergence of $a_n$ given convergence of $a_{2n},a_{3n},a_{2n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As in the title, I need to prove/disprove the following

> $a_n$ converges iif $a_{2n},a_{3n},a_{2n-1}$ converge.

One direction is pretty simple as they're subsequences of $a_n$, but the other direction is harder to prove/disprove (talking about showing $a_n$ converging).

I thought of using $a_n=(-1)^n$ but $a_{3n}$ doesn't converge. It still dosn't seem true as I'm looking for other counterexamples, but a proof would be welcome aswell of course!

Comment: Can you show that the three subsequences must have the same limit?

Comment: Not assuming $a_n$ converges? By my "example" this isn't true.

Comment: For any two consecutive terms from $(a_{3n})$ precisely one comes from $(a_{2n})$ and the other comes from $(a_{2n-1})$ but you are given that this sequence converges, so...

Comment: Without assuming that the full sequences converges a priori. But in your example, only two of the three subsequences converge.

Comment: Yes, but you are given that three specific subsequences converge. $a_n = (-1)^n$ doesn't satisfy that condition.

Comment: Which is why I said it didn't work. Didn't you read?

Comment: I did. But you commented 'Not assuming $a_n$ converges? By my "example" this isn't true.', so it seemed necessary to remind you that it isn't an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$ converge to different values. Since $a_{3n}$ alternates between these two subsequences, it diverges. Therefore, if all three subsequences converge, $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$ must converge to the same value, and so $a_n$ also converges.

Comment: Does it cover all the cases?

Comment: @learnmore sure it does. All that is needed is that the three subsequences converge.